# 10013 error (AccessDenied) on Silverlight Socet application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, network-programming

I am writing silverlight 3 application which is working on network.
It works like client-server application. There is WinForm application for server and silverlight application for client.
I use TcpListener on server and connect from client to it with Socket.
In local network it works fine, but when I try to use it from internet it don't connect to server.
I use IP address on local network and real IP with port number for internet version.
I get error 10013 AccessDenied.
Port number is correct and access policy exist.
Firewall is turned of.
Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that computer, where hosted website hasn't real IP address, and I couldn't connect to it from internet. I added Real IP address and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the general availability of the connection from your machine to the Internet server with telnet  ?

Comment: No I havn't. I don't know how to do that. Can you explain how to check?